# How can I use Qt Network Authorization for Azure AD OAuth2

Tags: qt, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to adapt the Qt Network Authorization [OAuth2 example for Reddit](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtnetworkauth-redditclient-example.html) to work with Azure AD.
I went to https://portal.azure.com/ -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations then clicked "New application registration" and entered:

- Name: QtNetworkAuthProject
- Application type: Name
- Redirect URI: http://localhost:1337/

[image: Azure Create]

I copied the resulting Application ID into the app then got the URIs from [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx):

- Authorization Code Request: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
- Access Token Request: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

The first part appears to work; the webpage opens and asks me to authenticate the login. But then the token request seems to fail. My logging shows:

```
AzureWrapper::grant()+
setModifyParametersFunction(): stage = RequestingAuthorization
AzureWrapper::grant()-
statusChanged(): status = TemporaryCredentialsReceived
setModifyParametersFunction(): stage = RequestingAccessToken
qt.networkauth.oauth2: Unexpected call
qt.networkauth.replyhandler: Error transferring https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token - server replied: Bad Request
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Hi Parsley,  I'm not aware of Qt Network Authorization, But since you want to integrate your app with AAD and use Authorization Code Grant Flow, it'd better use [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, but there isn't one for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD needs in either the authorization code request or in the access token request the App ID URI of the target web API (secured resource) that you want to use. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

You can add this extra resource parameter in the authorization code request like this:

```
oauth2.setModifyParametersFunction([](QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QVariantMap* parameters) {
    if (stage == QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAuthorization) {
        parameters->insert("resource", "<App ID URI>");
    }
});
```